# Fuzzy match digits

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that includes a date of birth ("dob") field but there are frequent typos. I'm trying to match records where the "dob" can be off by one or two digits. I'm not trying to look for dates close to the "dob" (eg `difftime`) because they typos could be in the year or month portion. I think `agrep` is the right tool since you can match with substitutions, but can't get it to work as I want.

The code I've tried to match dates with

```
df <- data.frame(dob = c(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2015-05-05"), as.Date("2011-11-11")))
df %>% filter(agrepl("2011-11-10", dob, max.distance=list(sub=2)))
```

returns the row with 2011-11-11 as I'd expect.
However, it only returns matches if the date is one digit is off. Even if I set `sub=5`, it doesn't seem to change the results. I want matches where up to two digits can be wrong. eg

```
df %>% filter(agrepl("2011-02-11", dob, max.distance=list(sub=2)))
```

would still return 2011-11-11

Comment: Yes, because it counts characters as strings. It does not know months/days/years etc.

Comment: My problem is that the code does not return true for 2011-11-11. I'd like to modify it so that it does.

Comment: Then what's wrong with this? `df %>% filter(agrepl("2011-02-11", dob, max.distance = 2))`?

Comment: What about `df %>% filter(agrepl("2011-11-11", dob, max.distance = list(all = 2)))`?

Comment: That does work, but I don't want matches with insertions or deletions. Only substitutions.

Comment: You can also check the length then

Comment: So does the subs option just not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the maximum tolerance for `cost` along with `substitutions` in the `max.distance` argument seems to do the trick.

Try

```
df %>% filter(agrepl("2011-02-11", dob, max.distance=list(sub=2, cost=2)))
```